# How to create an Amazon EC2 AMI from an instance?

Tags: virtualization, amazon-ec2, cloud

How to create an EC2 AMI from an instance?

Ok, so I got an EC2 account. I launched an instance with Fedora 8, Apache, MySQL PHP. I also configured some things and installed Piwik. "Cool...", I thought, "... I should now be able to create an AMI with that custom configuration. Instead, all I can find are guides with 300 steps on how to create one from scratch. Maybe I am dreaming but I thought this was the easy part.

What is the easiest way to create your own AMI with custom stuff installed?

Comment: I asked this question before EBS boot instances which make it every easy to create new images.