# AWS ec2 - Windows machine launched from AMI, isn't giving windows password

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a ec2 windows machine AMI, from Which I created an instance yesterday, I don;t remember its admin password, and I have been trying to get the windows password, but every time I try it says "it may take upto 30 minutes". It has been more then 15 hrs now, is there something fundamentally wrong here, how can i get access to my machine.

Comment: gee! what does it have to do with my junk mail folder?

Comment: This is why I am not getting my password :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454538/make-ami-from-ec2-w2008-instance-why-never-get-a-password?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows instance created from a custom AMI will inherit the password from the instance from which you created the AMI.

It will not generate PAssword. You have to login with the password you have configured on the instance from which you created this AMI.

This post is a typical scenario of **not reading the error message carefully**. :

[image]