# Creating EC2 Amazon instance from AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I have a t1 (free) EC2 Amazon instance running for an year already.

I created an AMI from this instance and then tried to create another EC2 t1 instance from this AMI (using right button menu / Launch).

The instance was created, its state has changed to running, but each time I try to retrieve an initial Windows password, I am getting the "**Your password is not ready**" notification.

I know it may take some time, but it is now **20 hours** already since I created an instance. Isn't it too long? Have somebody else experienced such a long delay?

Unfortunately, as I am working with free micro servers, Amazon support is not willing to help me.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **NOT** reading the complete message where it is telling you **Your password is not ready**.

The custom Windows AMI will inherit the password from the instance which it was created from. Read the message I pointed out above completely. You will find it yourself.

Comment: @slayedbulucifer: Nope, It doesn't say that, see a screenshot in my edited answer. But I am going to give it a try with my old password anyway.

Comment: Check my answer on another post here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/20606559/1251660. If it is a custom AMI, then It should have given you the said message unless you have Ec2SetPAssword Enabled/Disabled in Config.xml.

Comment: Yep, you were right, I can log in using the same password. Weird though,  I didn't have Ec2SetPAssword enabled and still didn't get this message. Amazon bug, I guess. Thanks.